# Spectacle exit status 1 - sass error

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, swagger, spectacle

```
    [4mRunning "sass:foundation_scss" (sass) task�[24m
    �[31mFatal error: The implementation option must be passed to the Sass 
    task.��[39m

    [Container] 2018/06/27 07:22:17 Command did not exit successfully 
     spectacle swagger.yaml exit status 1
```

I am trying to generate API documentation using spectacle and it fails with the error above.  I also tried

```
    npm i npm@latest -g
```

But even after that, the issue is the same.  A few days it used to work fine and I am getting this error now out of no where.

The implementation is done during build phase of a AWS CodePipeline and the build is running in a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.  The error occurred because one of the dependencies for spectacle was updated recently and current version of spectacle could not deal with that new dependency. The issue stays closed now.

More information at https://github.com/sourcey/spectacle/issues/156